# Conditional statement true in both parts of if-else-if ladder

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

If you have code like this:

```
if (A > X && B > Y)
{
   Action1();
}
else if(A > X || B > Y)
{
   Action2();
}
```

With `A > X` and `B > Y`, will both parts of the `if-else-if` ladder be executed?

I'm dealing with Java code where this is present. I normally work in C++, but am an extremely new (and sporadic) programmer in both languages.

Comment: No they don't. Except if your using some kind of language I don't know about.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, they won't both execute. It goes in order of how you've written them, and logically this makes sense; Even though the second one reads 'else if', you can still think of it as 'else'.

Consider a typical if/else block:

```
if(true){
   // Blah
} else{
   // Blah blah
}
```

If your first statement is true, you don't even bother looking at what needs to be done in the else case, because it is irrelevant. Similarly, if you have 'if/elseif', you won't waste your time looking at succeeding blocks because the first one is true.

A real world example could be assigning grades. You might try something like this:

```
if(grade > 90){
   // Student gets A
} else if(grade > 80){
   // Student gets B
} else if(grade > 70){
   // Student gets c
}
```

If the student got a 99%, all of these conditions are true. However, you're not going to assign the student A, B and C.

That's why order is important. If I executed this code, and put the B block before the A block, you would assign that same student with a B instead of an A, because the A block wouldn't be executed.

Answer (score 3):

If both `A > X` and `B > Y` are true then your code will only execute `Action1`. If one of the conditions is true it will execute `Action2`. If none are true, it will do nothing.

Using this:

```
if (A > X || B > Y) {
   Action2
   if (A > X && B > Y) {
      Action1                                    
   } 
}
```

will result in the possibility of both actions occurring when `A > X` and `B > Y` are both true.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about C, then only the first block that satisfies the condition is executed - after the control "enters" the conditional block it then "leaves" after all other conditions.

If you want such behavior, then just use two separate conditions - remove "else" and you have it.

Answer (score 1):

When the condition after `if` is true, only the first block is executed. The `else` block is *only* executed when the condition is false. It doesn't matter what's in the `else` block, it's not executed. The fact that the else block is another `if` statement is irrelevant; it won't be executed, so it will never perform the `(A > X || B > X)` test, and its body will not be executed even if that condition is true.